# Best way to kill Craw Maggots

Tags: borderlands

Is there some easy way to kill Craw Maggots in the Crawmerax fight? I play Siren and I usually have a friend playing Hunter. I've got most of the legendary (orange) weapons, I prefer SMGs, Sniper Rifles and Magnums but I can use any gun.

Armored Craw Worms go down in 3-4 shots from a Defiler (Corrosive Magnum), my Hellfire (Fire SMG) tears down Green Craw Worms in a couple seconds. NOTHING kills those insanely annoying Craw Maggots without a struggle.

I know Electric (and non-elemental?) weapons are recommended for them, but is there some trick to it? Several shots to the face with an Orion (Thunder Sniper) eventually kills them but it takes several seconds. Thunder Magnums and SMGs don't help much. Criticals are hard since they move so fast.

I've read the [Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Craw_Maggot) post on Craw Maggots (and all pages about Crawmerax) but these things are still by far he hardest part of the Crawmerax fight and they don't die to "two to three" shots as the wiki suggests (at least not with my guns).

Is there any reasonable way to kill Craw Maggots within 3-5 shots or 1-2 seconds of sustained fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are quite easily taken down using a electric [pounder](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Pounder), and hitting them in the eye.